# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position

Tags: python-3.x

When I use open and read syntax to open and read file in Python 3 and change files encoding, but this error happened. I want to convert a text with any encoding to UTF-8 and save it.

"sin3" has an unknown encoding,

```
fh= open(sin3, mode="r", encoding='utf8')
ss= fh.read()
```

> File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
>   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 34: invalid continuation byte

I used codecs and got this error:

```
fh= codecs.open(sin3, mode="r", encoding='utf8')
ss= fh.read()
```

> File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 679, in read
>           return self.reader.read(size)
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 482, in read
>           newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 34: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Your file isn't encoded with utf-8, so you can't open it with the utf-8 codec. You'll need to find some way to detect the actual encoding before you open it.

Comment: To put the same thing another way: when you open a file for reading, the `encoding` parameter needs to be the encoding the file is already in, not the encoding you want (you select that when you write the file).

Comment: Thanks for u'r support ! @Wooble,Thomas K

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

- Open the csv file in Sublime text editor.
- Save the file in utf-8 format.
- In sublime, Click File -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8

Then, you can read your file as usual:

> I would recommend using Pandas.

In Pandas, you can read it by using:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: This worked great for some of my files. But for a file that is too large to open in sublime text, I am out of luck. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fh = codecs.open(sin3, "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using Pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\akashkumar\\Downloads\\Customers.csv",encoding='latin1')
```